# Program which tells two different storys

Tags: code-challenge, popularity-contest

[this](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~manuel/obfuscate/westley.hint) code looks like a story but does nothing useful. My challenge for you guys is to write piece of code which sounds like another story but it must generate output - another story.

So the point of challenge to make valid code which can be read like a logical story/poem/tale, also it must generate output - another story/poem/tale.

It is not real code golf, so you can produce as much code as you need, also there is no need generate very long output with small piece of code, everything is about ingenuity. However there is only one limit in code, output needs to be longer then `Why did the chicken cross the road?`

My own opinion is not objective so the winner will be the top answer by votes. Will not accept an answer until 1st of November.

Comment: The [help pages](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) state "All questions on this site [...] should have an *objective* primary winning criterion".

Comment: Really cool idea though. :)

Comment: `answer_valid = false if !english_grammar_check(output)`  ?

Comment: if you drop the choose one of the 3 most highest voted answers, it could be [tag:popularity-contest]

Comment: Why is there a 'popularity-contest' -tag, if an objective winning criterion is a must for any question?

Comment: @shiona "Highest voted answer at `x` time" is objective.